# When are "from" and "by" interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Today I listened to a performance by Stephen Lynch in which he said "A public service anouncement from Stephen Lynch" which confused me, a non-native English speaker. Is the usage of "from" correct here? When can I use "from" instead of "by"?

Comment: If Tom Hanks records a public service announcement for the US government, then that is either "a PSA **by** Tom Hanks", or "a PSA **from** the US government". In your case, Stephen Lynch is both the _source_ and the _voice_ of the PSA, so he can choose to use by/from, as they are both correct for him (but not for Tom Hanks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either is possible, with slightly different meaning: the origin (*from*) or the immediate channel announcing it (*by*).

Because he himself is speaking it, you might expect *by*. But here it is a joke based on the common pattern *A public service announcement from ...* where *from* is used I think because the announcement may have been transmitted through various channels, but its origin is what matters, rather than the particular agency announcing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the use of "from" here has come about through the use of phrases like "now an announcement from our sponsor". And "take it (some advice) from me". In a sense the speaker is declaring himself the benefactor in bringing the public the information.

An announcement is arguably not commonly considered a 'creative artifact', so saying if he said 'by' it wouldn't necessarily portray authorship. More than point of origin (which isn't necessarily true of 'from' in my opinion' (_an announcement came from a loud-speaker), I think the speaker's intent is to say 'brought to you', in the sense of a sponsor or benefactor.

As to when 'from and by' are interchangeable. Where they can be used alternately *from* does tend to emphasise (metaphorical) movement or physical origination, where I think *by* emphasises a process or a creative agent.

> The lava was formed *from* melting rock

The lava came about as a metaphorical path of transition, originating with rock and passing through or arriving at the phase of melted rock.

> The lava was formed *by* melting rock

An agent or external cause (perhaps, as implied, the melting rock) was responsible for creating lava.

Perhaps slightly different in meaning though often interchanged in similar circumstances.